# Pandas dataframe values return Nonetype

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying out this Python API for google trends. it created a pandas dataframe where the first column is the date and the others the keywords in kw_list, the values representing how much people search for the keywords.

https://github.com/GeneralMills/pytrends

This is my code

```
from pytrends.request import TrendReq


# Login to Google. Only need to run this once, the rest of requests will use the same session.
pytrend = TrendReq()

# Create payload and capture API tokens.

pytrend.build_payload(kw_list=['adele', 'wat'])

interest_over_time_df = pytrend.interest_over_time()

c = print(interest_over_time_df.iloc[-1]['adele'])
print(c)
```

This outputs '5'. However, the type is Nonetype, so I can't compare this value to other values. How can I get the output as an integer?

Comment: in pandas its `dtype=int`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `c` as you have it now is a print statement, which is indeed a `NoneType`.

Try replacing

```
c = print(interest_over_time_df.iloc[-1]['adele'])
print(c)
```

with

```
c = int(interest_over_time_df.iloc[-1]['adele'])
print(c)
```

This prints `c`, which is explicitly cast as an `int`. Depending on how interest over time is calculated, you might actually want a float (not an int), so that you can compare for instance `1.0` to `1.1` if such values are possible. if that is the case, you can just replace `int` in my suggestion with `float`